# Facebook client crashes facebook SSO login dialog after changing facebook password

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I have encountered a crash using SSO to login to facebook. I could not find any reports in any of the forums of anything similar.

When we change user password on facebook site, within about 15 seconds android facebook client will notify user via notification bar that facebook authentication failed. If user reacts and logs in, our application SSO will pick up new token  with no problem.

If user changes the password, launches our app facebook request (like download of list of friends) before user reacted to facebook application notification and logged in with new password, we get the SSO crash, which erroneously notifies our application that user cancelled login.

Somehow facebook application login dialog (blue dialog) and SSO login dialog (white dialog) can't live together. If they are opened at the same time, SSO initiated instance of Facebook client crashes with following exception:

```
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at com.facebook.orca.common.util.Base64.c(Base64.java:497)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at com.facebook.orca.common.util.Base64.b(Base64.java:459)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth.b(ProxyAuth.java:36)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at com.facebook.katana.activity.PlatformDialogActivity.a(PlatformDialogActivity.java:127)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at com.facebook.orca.activity.FbFragmentActivity.onCreate(FbFragmentActivity.java:48)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
04-25 10:40:39.790: E/AndroidRuntime(5991): ... 11 more
```

Another hint is that little bit above that there is a window leaked non fatal exception within facebook application:
Activity com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth has leaked window `com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@406eecf0 that was originally added here`
Did anyone encounter similar crashes? I am really puzzled that nobody refers to those crashes, as far as google can find. I followed hackbook example when implementing this. I really don't have a clue what could be causing it.

Comment: I just reproduced the same crash with Go!Chat and Seismic applications installed from the market. It seems to be a facebook application bug.

Comment: I have reported the same issue to Facebook, who are looking into it: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/114390212025993

Comment: We had the same crash on Galaxy S II.

Answer (score 5):

Might not have to do with password changing but removing:

android:launchMode="singleInstance" from the AndroidManifest.xml

solved a similar bug for me (also java.lang.NullPointerException in com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.ProxyAuth)